# Send Dynamic Javascript values through PHP mail function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've created a form to generate additional fields based off of "number of guests."
The form is working as I'd like, but I am now struggling with trying to understand how to grab these dynamic values from the form and send them through PHP.

HTML -  Form

```
    <div class="contact-form">
  <form action="php/contact-form.php" class="contact-form" id="contactForm" method="post" name="contactform" role="form">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email*</label>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <label class="sr-only" for="guests">I promise to dance if you play...*</label>
      <textarea type="text" placeholder="I promise to dance if you play..." class="form-control" id="song" name="song"></textarea>
      <i class="fa fa-music form-control-feedback"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <label class="sr-only" for="guests">Other</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Other" class="form-control" id="other" name="other">
      <i class="fa fa-question form-control-feedback"></i>

    </div>
    <h4>Number of Guests</h4>
    <select class="form-control" onchange="numofGuests(this)">
      <option>Select number of guests</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback" id="guestForm"></div>

    <div id="contactFormResponse"></div>

    <input id="cfsubmit" type="submit" value="Send" class="submit-button btn btn-default">
  </form>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT to generate more fields based of "Number of Guests" selection

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function numofGuests(val) {
    document.getElementById('guestForm').innerHTML = "";
    for (i = 0; i < parseInt(val.value); i++) { 
        document.getElementById('guestFormOne').innerHTML += '<h4>Guest '+(i+1)+'</h4><input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" id="guest'+(i+1)+'_name" name="guest_name"><div class="col-sm-4"><select class="form-control" id="guest'+(i+1)+'_meal" name="guest_meal"><option>Meal Choice</option> <option>Buffet</option><option>Gluten Free</option><option>Dairy Free</option><option>Vegan</option></select></div><div class="col-sm-4"><select class="form-control" id="guest'+(i+1)+'_age" name="guest_age"><option>Age</option><option>Adult</option><option>Child under 5</option><option>Child 6 - 12</option></select></div><div class="col-sm-4"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="guest'+(i+1)+'_allergy" name="guest_allergy" placeholder="Allergies?"></div>';
    }      
}    

    </script>
```

PHP Sending the variables

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $song = $_POST['song'];
    $other = $_POST['other'];

// Stuck here on how to grab these variables from the 
// Javascript function numofGuests and send them in an email
    $name = $_POST['guest_name'];
    $meal = $_POST['guest_meal'];
    $age = $_POST['guest_age'];
    $allergy = $_POST['guest_allergy'];


    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
      $message .= "\n The form is submitted at: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   }

    $from = $email;
    $subject = 'Wedding Website - RSVP';

    $body = "From: $email\n 
             Song suggestions: $song\n
             Additional Comments: $other\n
             \n
             --- Guests ---\n
             Name: $name | Meal: $meal | Age: $age | Allergies: $allergy";
```

I'm confused on how I would have the email $body display the $name, $meal, $age and $allergy of each guest that is entered. Doing that whether 1 guest is selected, or for 6.

Comment: I recommend learning AJAX, ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand client-side vs. server side scripting.

On a simple level:

**Client-side:** (Javascript) the work you do to dynamically "change" content on the page is all done on the client's browser by default (the server side - where your PHP scripts reside - do not know anything about these Javascript changes).

**Server side:** this includes all your PHP scripts - scripts that run "in the background" in order to generate possible dynamic content to display on your web page. When a form is submitted for example, this form can be POSTed to a PHP script (`php/contact-form.php`) in your case, and this PHP script will then run on the server side. Javascript variables are not passed unless you used Javascript to dynamically update one or more of your form's fields.

So if you are changing something with Javascript, and say you are feeding some data into a `<input type="hidden" />`  variable, then that value will be POSTed to your PHP script once the form is *submitted*.

Once you have grasped the above two concepts, then learn Ajax, as suggested above. Ajax will allow the Javascript to dynamically talk to your PHP script in the background without the user needing to submit the form (this is just a simple example).

Hope that helps but let me know if you have questions or if I didn't answer the question.